# Which hardware specification should one be looking for to optimize the visualization of a tendinopathy through ultrasound?

Tags: imaging, tendons

The 2019 study {1} reports that hip abductor tendon pathology is better visualized by 3.0 Tesla MRIs than by 1.5 Tesla MRIs.

The 2014 study {2} also mentions the usefulness of high teslas for tendon analysis:

> MRI of tendons and ligaments benefits from high spatial resolution. Stronger magnetic fields lead to higher signal-to-noise ratios and improvements in image resolution; **for this reason, 3-T MRI may be more sensitive than 1.5 T for detection of partial thickness tears** [26]. Alternatively, higher resolution may be achieved by using a local surface coil [27]. Imaging with shorter echo times improves sensitivity to tendon changes, although this may come at the expense of specificity [28,29]. T2 weighted images are helpful for identifying fluid signal in tendon or ligament tears (Figure 5) as well as for demonstrating changes in the surrounding tissues [30]. If the orientation of a tendon changes over its course, magic angle effects may be problematic; it may therefore be helpful to acquire images with a sufficiently long echo time to avoid these artefacts.

Which hardware specification should one be looking for to optimize the visualization of a tendinopathy through ultrasound?

---

References:

- {1} Oehler, Nicola, Julia Kristin Ruby, André Strahl, Rainer Maas, Wolfgang Ruether, and Andreas Niemeier. "Hip abductor tendon pathology visualized by 1.5 versus 3. 0 Tesla MRIs." Archives of Orthopaedic and Trauma Surgery (2019): 1-9. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/31243547; https://doi.org/10.1007/s00402-019-03228-1
- {2} Hodgson, R. J., P. J. O'Connor, and A. J. Grainger. "Tendon and ligament imaging." The British journal of radiology (2014).
  Harvard ; https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=16366672343955449638&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ;
  http://www.birpublications.org/doi/full/10.1259/bjr/34786470

Comment: Why do you give background on MRI while asking a question about ultrasound?

Comment: @BryanKrause to give an example of an important hardware specification for another imaging device also commonly used to non-invasively visualize tendons.